# 3D Dome in gnuplot with sqrt(x) function

Tags: function, graph, 3d, gnuplot

I have to "draw" a 3d function in gnuplot with the function `sqrt(1-x**2+y**2)`, where the graph looks like a dome.
[image: it should look like this]

I am supposed to do it with unset parametric.

I just couldnt find out how to do it, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your function `sqrt(1-x**2+y**2)` doesn’t represent the dome shape. The correct formula would be `sqrt(1-(x**2+y**2))`.

Then, even if you specify `unset parametric`, you can draw a dome shape by giving the function form to splot.

```
unset parametric

set xrange [-1.2:1.2]
set yrange [-1.2:1.2]
set isosamples 20,20

splot real(sqrt(1-(x**2+y**2))), sqrt(1-(x**2+y**2))
```

Many of the mathematical functions in gnuplot support complex numbers. `sqrt(x)` returns a complex number if x is negative. Note that such a value is treated like a missing value on a plot.

This script generates a figure like this (on pngcairo terminal).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that was really helpful